# change color of borderless window in win32

Tags: windows, win32gui

I'm creating a borderless window, similar to https://github.com/melak47/BorderlessWindow and use it to create a swapchain and draw with vulkan into it.

To get the borderless window (with aero shadow) I use: DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea up to 1 pixel.
I can draw on top of that last pixel border with my swapchain. After some googling I understand that this is the only way to do it.

Unfortunately when resizing, no matter how well I sync to the compositor, I still get occasional flashes of the **bright white** border.

To make this acceptable, I'd like to use a more neutral color for the border. How do I achieve this?

Edit: If I increase the border to 10 pixel, I get this:
[image]
(the green and red boxes are drawn by vulkan, with no transparency, the frame is cleared to alpha of zero)

Where does this white come from?

Note: This is not the accent color.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

There is an undocumented function to set additional DWM settings of a window: https://gist.github.com/ysc3839/b08d2bff1c7dacde529bed1d37e85ccf

This is also used to make blurred transparency and can change the border color with the ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT enum.